# Duplicate printf while forking

Tags: c, unix, fork

I'm using fork to make process tree here's the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdlib.h>    

int main () {


pid_t pid;
printf("Parent of all: %ld\n",(long)getpid());

pid = fork();

if(pid == -1){
   perror("fork failed");
   exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
else if (pid == 0){
   pid = fork();
   printf("Child with id: %ld and its Parent id: %ld \n", (long)getpid(),(long)getppid()); 

   if(pid > 0){
      pid = fork();
      printf("Child with id: %ld and its Parent id: %ld \n", (long)getpid(),(long)getppid());    
      _exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
   }
}
else{
   int status;
   waitpid(pid, &status, 0);
}
   return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

after `else if` the `printf` line passes to a child so i get the same thing printed twice as u can see in results here [results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pmkGP.png) can i somehow prevent this from happening?

Comment: What's happening? Please post all the relevant information in the question, not in a link or image.

Comment: "Results" should be pasted as text on the site (as part of the question), rather than as a screenshot link. Screenshots aren't searchable, can't be copy/pasted, require more bandwidth to consume, and otherwise add less value than in-line text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call fork both the parent and child process will continue executing from the same point, which means they will both execute `printf("child with id...)`.